# CSS Hidden DIV Form Submit

Tags: css, forms, html, submit, form-submit

Using CSS, when a link is clicked it brings up a hidden DIV that contains a form. The user will then enter information and then submit the form.  I'd like the hidden DIV to remain visible, and a 'success message' to be displayed after submission.  Then the user will have the option of closing the DIV.  I can't get it to work without reloading the page, which causes the DIV to become hidden again. Any ideas?

```
<body>
       <a href="javascript:showDiv()" style="color: #fff;">Click Me</a>

        <!--POPUP-->

        <div id="hideshow" style="visibility:hidden;">
            <div id="fade"></div>
            <div class="popup_block">
                <div class="popup">
            <a href="javascript:hideDiv()">
              <img src="images/icon_close.png" class="cntrl" title="Close" />
              </a>
                    <h3>Remove Camper</h3>
                    <form method="post" onsubmit="email.php">
                    <p><input name="Name" type="text" /></p>
                    <p><input name="Submit" type="submit" value="submit" /></p>
                </form>
                <div id="status" style="display:none;">success</div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!--END POPUP-->

        <script language=javascript type='text/javascript'> 
        function hideDiv() { 
        if (document.getElementById) { // DOM3 = IE5, NS6 
        document.getElementById('hideshow').style.visibility = 'hidden'; 
        } 
        else { 
        if (document.layers) { // Netscape 4 
        document.hideshow.visibility = 'hidden'; 
        } 
        else { // IE 4 
        document.all.hideshow.style.visibility = 'hidden'; 
        } 
        } 
        }

        function showDiv() { 
        if (document.getElementById) { // DOM3 = IE5, NS6 
        document.getElementById('hideshow').style.visibility = 'visible'; 
        } 
        else { 
        if (document.layers) { // Netscape 4 
        document.hideshow.visibility = 'visible'; 
        } 
        else { // IE 4 
        document.all.hideshow.style.visibility = 'visible'; 
        } 
        } 
        } 
        </script>

</body>
```

Comment: All I have to say is that I apologize that you still seem to need to support IE/Netscape 4. Wow.

Comment: @Russell: You apologize?  So it's YOUR fault!  @Everyone: Get 'im!

Comment: It was the other Russell, I swear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forms by default submit content by changing to the specified page in its 'action' attribute. You will need to build additional scripts to prevent it from doing that and submit the data using either AJAX or jQuery then process the result.

Or you could simply use whatever language you're programming in to set the default visibility for the division. If the form data exists, display it by default, otherwise hide it by default.

Comment: Combined these two plugins!
http://malsup.com/jquery/form/
http://famspam.com/facebox

Answer (score 0):

How about using an AJAX call to post the form instead of posting back the whole page?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a "submit" type for your button, you can use a "button" type and use a script   called by onclick which will use ajax to submit the form and do whatever is necessary.

This defeats slightly the meaning of a form, but works well. You might also want to think about using a javascript library like prototype or similar (jquery, etc) that gives you the functionality to create a get or post array of your form in order to make it easier.